# I'm trying to make a dictionary whose name is defined by user input. How do I do this?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I ran into a problem when I tried to do something like this:

```
a=input()
b=input()
c=input()
a's user input = {'y': b, 'z': c}
```

Comment: Don't do this. How would you refer to it anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a dictionary to store your dictionaries. That allows you to use the input as dictionary key:

```
mydicts = {}

a=input()
b=input()
c=input()
mydicts[a] = {'y': b, 'z': c}
```

Then later you can retrieve in the same way using `mydicts[]`. This will print the value of `b` when `some_var` matches `a`:

```
print(mydicts[some_var]['y'])
```

Comment: I'll try that out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess it should be sth like this:

```
d = {}
u_key = ''

while (u_key != 'END'):
    u_key = input('Enter key:\n')
    d[u_key] = input(f'Enter value for {u_key}\n')

print(d)
```